# Laravel: Failed opening required file

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel implementation of AggCatAuth.  When I try to load the page (hosted on a homestead vm), I get the following error:

```
main(): Failed opening required 'class.aggcatauth.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

The class AggCatAuth is referenced in the following block with config.php

```
require_once('config.php');
require_once('class.aggcatauth.php');
```

Config.php loads fine, even though both files are in the same directory and have the same permissions.

1. What are some reasons that a required file would fail to open?
2. The error message refers to "include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR'".  Which file within the laravel framework specifies the paths to include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a single file that lists all the paths to include, but I was able to find the files which specify include paths using the grep command:

```
Grep -rl . -e "set_include_path"
```

Likewise the paths which are already included can be determined by running

```
Get_include_path()
```